# Markov chain sub-stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, stochastic-processes

I was just curious if a Markov chain defined using a sub-stochastic matrix where the row entries do not have to sum to 1, works in the same way as a "normal" stochastic matrix? I.e.,

$x_f A = x_i$,

where $A$ is the sub-stochastic matrix?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that "sub-stochastic" means that every row has sum less than $1$.  Is that accurate?

Comment: If $A$ is substochastic, then presumably the transition probabilities (from state $i$ to state $j$) don't add up to $1$ (over all states $j$).  If we want to interpret $A$ in the same kind of way, you need to answer a question about the situation being modeled: if we don't transition from state $i$ to *some state* $j$, what *else* can happen?

Comment: Hi. Yes, that is the definition that I am considering.

Comment: See my other comment.  What exactly the Markov chain which is "described using a sub-stochastic matrix"?  For example, what Markov chain is described by the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0.5&0\\0&0}?
$$